# SQL - user-defined variables & client session confusion?

Tags: mysql, sql, session, stored-procedures, scope

So I have some user defined variables in a stored procedure, it looks something like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`rsgarci1`@`%` PROCEDURE `closestTimestampSun`()
BEGIN 


OPEN tstamp_cursor;
get_timestamp: LOOP 

  SELECT @MID:=m.vID, @MX:=m.x , @MY:=m.y , @MT:=m.timestamp FROM movementSunTemp2 m
  WHERE m.vID = cSID 
  AND m.timestamp = (SELECT MAX(T.timestamp) 
                     FROM (SELECT mm.timestamp FROM movementSunTemp2 mm WHERE mm.vID = cSID AND mm.timestamp <= ctstamp)AS T);

INSERT INTO sunFromLocation(`ctimestamp`,`cID`,`vID`,`x`,`y`,`mtimestamp`)

VALUES(ctstamp,cSID,@MID,@MX,@MY,@MT); 
END LOOP get_timestamp; 
close tstamp_cursor;
END
```

I cut out a bit in the middle, but thats the gist of it.

According to the [mySQL Page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) on it it says:

> User-defined variables are session-specific. That is, a user variable defined by one client cannot be seen or used by other clients. All variables for a given client session are automatically freed when that client exits.

What does this exactly mean? I am new to SQL so I'm really confused on what exactly constitutes a "user-session/client". Does the client session end when the procedure exits? Does it end when I turn off the computer that is running the query? So then if I wanted to use variables like `@variable` in a query, I have to keep the computer on the whole time?

This may be a dumb question, but I'm really confused, so any help would greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user session is specific to the client you are using - MySQL development environment in this case. The variables you defined in the session will not be accessible to others who are connected to the same database. Once you close the session, the life of your variables expire. And if you define variables in a procedure, they are only accessible in the procedure as their scope is the procedure itself.

Comment: Thanks! That makes a bit more sense. But I guess my question really is what constitutes a `session`, I'll edit my question to make it more clear. Does the session end when the procedure finishes? Or does the session end when I turn off the computer that I'm running the query on? It's the first one right?

Comment: the session ends only when you exit out of your development environment.More specifically if you have multiple tabs open, each constitutes its own session.